Unable to edit Marketing Cloud SF Connector Permission Set to sync new object to MC
I cannot seem to edit the permission set Marketing Cloud Connect to add a new object so I can sync it in marketing cloud. I've set up the following in both systems, and I do not have the edit button available.

My user has the permission sets for MC Connnect, all of them
My user has the two boxes checked, MC for AppExchange User and MC for AppExchange Admin
My usernames across the two are integrated
My user is a sys admin in both systems






